# Remove all duplicates in a list of list (not including the original)

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of lists and I want to remove all the duplicates so that the similar lists will not appear at all in the new list.

```
k = [[1, 2], [4], [5, 6, 2], [1, 2], [3], [4]]

output == [[5,6,2], [3]]
```

So for example, `[1,2]` have a duplicate so it should not appear in the final list at all. This is different from what others have asked as they wanted to keep one copy of the duplicate in the final list.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve it?

Comment: @TYL use k.count for every item. if count > 1, than desroy it

Comment: I was thinking of using a nested for loop to compare each item i with i+1 but seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` to count the number of occurrences of a element.

## Approach 1 Time complexity *`O(n^2)`*

```
final=[]
for i in k:
    if k.count(i)==1:
        final.append(i)
print(final)
```

---

```
[[5, 6, 2], [3]]
```

---

Pythonic way to write this is :

```
final=[i for i in k if k.count(i)==1]
```

---

## Approach 2 Time complexity *`O(n^2)`*

Or you can search if *ith* element is present in rest of the list or not. If present don't add it to`final`.

```
for i,lst in enumerate(k):
    if lst not in k[:i]+k[i+1:]:
        final.append(lst)
print(final)
```

---

output

```
[[5, 6, 2], [3]]
```

pythonic way to write this:

```
final=[i for i,lst in enumerate(k) if lst not in k[:i]+k[i+1:]]
```

## Approach 3 Time complexity is *`O(n)`*

You can achieve this in `O(n)` by using dictionaries.

```
dic={}
k=list(map(tuple,k))   #Since key values in dictionary should always be immutable.
for i in k:
    dic[i]=dic.setdefault(i,0)+1

final=[]

for k in dic:
    if dic[k]== 1:
        final.append(list(k))
```

Comment: @AndyG I looked up in ics.uci documentation(https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt) `setdefault` is `O(1)` , `append` in `list` is `O(1)` , lookup in `dictionary` i.e. `dict[i]` is `O(1)`. So, the total time complexity would be `O(2n)` which is written to `O(n)`. Correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For the general problem of dropping duplicates, you could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), although it requires hashable values.

```
import collections

def drop_all_duplicates(values):
    # As of CPython 3.7, Counter remembers insertion order.
    value_counts = collections.Counter(values)
    return (value for value, count in value_counts.items() if count == 1)

>>> list(drop_all_duplicates([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6])
[2, 4, 6]
```

This could be expanded to cover non-hashable values by accepting a function that converts them to hashable (e.g. a function that converts lists to tuples).

Comment: check the edited answer. I used dictionaries to reduce the time complexity to `O(n)`.